@Profile is not working expected for @KafkaListener
i used @Profile("Training") AND @KafkaListener even am passing random profile also the KafkaListener is working. Excepted to work only when profile is matched
@Profile("training")
@KafkaListener(id = "my_grp", topicPartitions = {
        @TopicPartition(topic = KafkaTopicConstants.MY_TOPIC, partitions = {"0", "1", "2","3","4","5"})
}, concurrency = KafkaTopicConstants.PARTITION_COUNT)
public void consumeRequest(ConsumerRecord<String,RequestedUrlData> record) {
    try {
            log.error("Consuming Data   :::: ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
       log.error("Exception while consuming ",e);
    }
}

this class is annotated with the @Service

It should be on the class not the method.

@M.Deinum profile does not work for method ?

It doesn't only on components or methods which create beans (those annotated with @Bean). \

The spring kafka documentation says this about the @KafkaListener annotation

The @KafkaListener annotation is used to designate a bean method as a listener for a listener container. The bean is wrapped in a MessagingMessageListenerAdapter configured with various features, such as converters to convert the data, if necessary, to match the method parameters.

Spring Kafka
So the annotation is actually used on a bean method and doesn't mean the method it is annotated with is a bean. It just wraps that method with the Listener adapter. So we can't control if that is created or not by annotating the method with @Profile. However annotating the class with @Profile will stop the @Service bean from being created and thereby will not create the kafka listener because no bean method is annotated with @KafkaListener now.
